# Is the Label Text Changes while Data bounding?

Tags: asp.net

I have changed label text for showing process for Button Click,We are binding Data to three drop down lists and two grids in that Button click Event.

I wrote for Grid On Item Databound :

```
lblLoad.Text = "Jobs Grid :" + dgvJobs.Items.Count + " Out of "+ JobsCount +" are loaded";
```

for Dropdown list OnDataBinding:

```
lblLoad.Text = "Job Numbers :" + ddlJobNumber.Items.Count + "  Out of " + JobsNumbersCount + " are loaded";
```

Is this correct ? Is this label text changes as progress . ? Currently This Label is showing after completing all the data is bounded.Please show me the way to achieve this as progress.

Thanks ,Rakesh

Comment: You could use an asp.net-ajax [`UpdateProgress control`](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updateprogress-control/). But that would only show an image during the roundtrip to the server. I'm afraid that you haven't yet understood the difference between Winforms and ASP.NET. You cannot update the client's browser on changes at the server (easily).

Comment: The requirement is to show the text as progress :(

Answer (score 0):

No, it wont changes as progress (read MSDN article - [ASP.NET Page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). Instead you can create a `StringBuilder` object, append text and finally assign it to `Label.Text`.

PS: You can enabled the [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx) if you want to see/view *diagnostic* information about a single request for an ASP.NET page.

Comment: I assume that the only reason for the label is to show the progress. I dont see how a stringbuilder would help here. The result would always be _"Job Numbers : 100  Out of 100 are loaded"_ (for example).

Comment: @TimSchmelter And *we* know (; that is **impossible**.

Answer (score 0):

You binding process is happening in the server, and if you update the Label text during this process, the text is changed in the server only. When the process is finished and html is sent to the client, only then the label text is shown.

You need to change the label text in client side according to the progress. If you want just "Please Wait" message you can do that with asp.net `UpdatePanel` and `UpdateProgress`, look here: http://weblogs.asp.net/stoianbucovich/archive/2008/01/30/asp-net-2-0-ajax-update-panel-and-update-progress.aspx.

If you want more to show the real progress percentage, you need much more complex code in the client, but I don't think it worth the effort. Binding is not such a long progress.